# How to Use PHP to Trigger a JS onClick Event

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I have a signup form that has an input box hidden from view unless a link is clicked. Here's the code:

```
<a id="showCoupon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleCoupon();">
     <?php _e('Have a coupon?','mysite'); ?>
</a>
```

If the coupon GET variable is set, I want the input box to be visible and prefilled with the supplied data. I added PHP to check for the presence of a GET variable like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['coupon'])) {
    $coupon = $_GET['coupon'];
}
?>
```

In addition, the input box has been modified to use the value of `$coupon`, if set. Now, I can't figure out how to trigger the JS event `toggleCoupon();`.

I modifying the PHP function to click the link like this:

```
if ( isset($_GET['coupon']) ) {
   $coupon = $_GET['coupon'];
   echo "<script>$('#showCoupon').trigger('click');</script>";
}
?>
```

So far, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you just want to be able to execute some JavaScript when the user clicks the link?

Comment: No, I want to prefill a text field with a get variable which is hidden from default view unless a link is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showCoupon').trigger('click');
});

</script>
```

When the document loads, jQuery will trigger the click even of the element with the id of `showCoupon`

Comment: That worked, thanks! So, I was missing the $(document).ready? Thought I didn't need it since it was being executed by PHP, not on page load necessarily.

Comment: The code is not being executed by PHP. PHP is a server side language. Your simply telling the page to load that script if a certain circumstance is met. But the actual running of that script is not going to happen until the page loads, in this case when the DOM is ready

Comment: Got it, that makes sense! I'll mark your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Downvoted for kludge. The correct way is not to simulate a click, the correct way is to not hide the element in the first place.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen The question was "how can I trigger event `x`" - I showed him how he could do so.

Comment: @Evan: Yes, I can see the OP was [asking the wrong question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen So why down-vote my answer when it was a perfectly acceptable solution to his question?

Comment: @Evan: Perhaps to the question, but not to the problem.

Comment: Worked great Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a kludge like that. That's awful.

Instead, on the server side, don't output the piece of code (CSS class, "display: none;", whatnot) that hides the element in the first place, if the URL parameter is provided.

If the element is hidden by JavaScript, pass it a value indicating that the initial state should be visible.